# Why doesn't Pain use other paths when his bodies are killed?

Tags: naruto

During the Naruto vs Pain fight (before Edo Tensei), he has 6 bodies that he controls via Chakra and each body has the power of one path.

When Naruto kills anyone of them, it's stated that he loses usage to that particular power of path until he has another body for that.

My doubt is that since its just bodies controlled by chakra, why doesn't he use the remaining pain to use all the paths?

For example, if the summoning path dies, Why can't he use that path through the Yahiko pain or some other pain?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure but my guess is that Kishimoto did that on purpose because if he didn't Naruto wouldn't have a chance against Pain, so basically it's just his way of making Pain NOT perfect leaving the others with a possibility of revealing his secret(weakness) and getting a chance to fight back (since naruto must win at the end).

Comment: Similar to how Might Guy was on a mission, ("conveniently") when Pain attacked.

Answer (score 0):

Pain is supposed to have implanted these abilities in the corpses, so he supposedly implanted one in a each of the pain only, probably because of the limit of power of someone not from the uzumaki clan or having those kind of abilities. Their chakra system could be fried and then he wouldn't be able to use 'em

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.